# VBA Excel FormulaR1C1 "Application Defined or Object Defined Error"?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a very simple piece of code that averages 600 values into 60 values by averaging every 10 values using a For loop.

This code is throwing an error saying "Application Defined or Object Defined Error" somewhere in the R1C1 formula and I cannot figure out why - I assume it has something to do with my variables. Anyone know how to do this?

```
Sub Averaging10()

Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Z As Double

X = 5
Y = 5
Z = 0

For X = 5 To 65

Z = Y + 9

    Cells(5, X).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-3], Z : RC[-3], Z])"

Y = Y + 10

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I see now, I have an extra square bracket at the end. Still throwing errors, but I'll fix them. Sorry, disregard.

Comment: Either you're attempting to mix R1C1 and A1 syntax, which you can't do - or you're trying to pass the value of `Z` to your formula whereas at the moment you're actually passing the literal string "Z"

Comment: By fortunate coincidence, the community [recently discussed adding urgency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) to questions - please read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra Bracket in there. Try this:

```
Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Z As Double

X = 5
Y = 5
Z = 0

For X = 5 To 65
    Z = Y + 9
    Cells(5, X).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-3], Z : RC[-3], Z)"
    Y = Y + 10
Next
```